# Recognising a browser

Tags: php, html, web, server-side

I haven't coded anything at the moment as I'm looking for best practice on how to achieve the follow.

Taking Facebook as an example, it can recognise a 'known' browser (i.e. one which has been logged into before) and one which isn't (i.e. that has not logged in before) and if it hasn't been logged into before it asks for a confirmation code.

What methods would be best for 'recognising a browser'? A unique generated cookie could be stored on a browser, user-agent could possibly be stored? I'm not sure the worth in storing IP as most are dynamic.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: they drop a cookie with a key assigned to the account. if the cookie doesn't exist then its a never before used browser and so a new key needs to be generated and authed via the confirmation email that is sent.

Comment: i highly doubt that, i remove cookies after every browser shutdown and still can log in.

Comment: I'll place money on you not removing all of them.  The only other way would be IP match but thats unreliable

Comment: you can be sure i remove ALL of them, like the answer states there is a way to use geographical location of the user or saving the browser/computer data, like version, hardware configuration etc.

Comment: There is but its unreliable and highly unlikely the method used.  Take for example BT (major UK ISP) I am in say sheffield but their network routes me out via an external ip allocated to London (few hundred Km difference) so as far as geocoding is concerned I'm in london.  Now for geocoding for consistant login you would have to have it within a <=25km limit at a max not just say "well its in the same country".  Browser version can be spoofed/changed by browsers hardware info not public via browser.  Its cookies promise you.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to read this http://www.nikcub.com/posts/facebook-fixes-logout-issue-explains-cookies  check the "The other cookies" section.  You're looking for the datr, lu etc they persist after log out and won't be cleared by using the browser built in "clear cookies" button (infact 99% of cookies wont clear using that method)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against requiring a user to validate every browser they use - especially since something like that could cause problems even with something as simple as clearing out cookies.

I believe Facebook checks your IP against a geolocation database to see roughly where you are in the world. If your location changes significantly (ie. more than is reasonable for work or school) then it will lock your account and ask you to confirm your identity.

In this way, you sort of get "regions" that you tell Facebook it's okay for you to be. If you haven't been in a region for a while, it'll probably drop that off the allowed list (since you were probably only there on vacation or something)

All that said, personally I think it's too much work to be worth it. If users already have a password protecting their account, then (assuming you have hashed it correctly in your database) it is entirely the user's responsibility to maintain their account security. If you post your photos and personal info behind the password "password", you should be surprised to see it stolen.